# Postscript: Draw Logo in upper left corner in any page size

Tags: postscript

I need to **draw Logo to the existing pdf files into the top left corner**. Currently, I hard-coded the y position in the postscript. I need to change the y position as per the current page size of the using pdf file. As same like Logo, I need to draw rectangle also. there also i hard coded the parameters.

My Script ---

```
<<
    /PageSize [595 842]
    /EndPage {
        exch pop 2 lt {
            gsave
                20 720 translate     
                40 40 scale        
                77                   
                81                  
                8                    
                [77 0 0 -81 0 81]      
                (Logo.jpg) (r) file /DCTDecode filter 
                false                 
                3                   
                colorimage  
            grestore
            gsave           
                newpath 10 10 60 820 rectstroke
                /_WM_str (Office of XXXX,XXXX) def
                /Helvetica [40 0 0 40 0 0] selectfont
                /DeviceRGB setcolorspace
                0.96 0.96 0.96 setcolor
                currentpagedevice/PageSize get aload pop
                2 div exch 12 div exch translate 90 rotate
                newpath
                _WM_str stringwidth pop 2 div neg 0 moveto
                _WM_str show                
            grestore
            true
        } { false } ifelse
    }bind
>>setpagedevice
```

Using following command, i created output file.

> gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOSAFER -dNOPAUSE
>   -sOutputFile=output.pdf -dPDFFitPage -dAutoRotatePages=/None -f test.ps 1001.pdf

I need to know, how to position logo in upper left corner and draw rectangle from bottom to top around the logo like stamping?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the current media size from the page device dictionary :

currentpagedevice /PageSize get

that gives you the width and height of the media, and you can calculate from that where the top left corner is.

The layout of the portion you are adding is up to you, but you should be able to use the width and height to calculate an appropriate scale factor, as well as figuring out where the remaining portions of your graphic will go.

```
%!
<<
    /PageSize [595 842]
    /EndPage {
        exch pop 2 lt {
            currentpagedevice /PageSize get  %% stack has array [width height]
            0 0 moveto                       %% start at bottom left
            dup 1 get                        %% copy array, get height
            0 exch lineto                    %% line to top left 
            dup 0 get                        %% copy array get width
            10 div cvi 0 rlineto             %% horizontal line from top left, 1/10th of width
            1 get                            %% get height from array
            neg 0 exch rlineto               %% vertical line to bottom of page
            closepath                        %% close path to origin
            0.5 setgray stroke
            true
        } { false } ifelse
    }bind
>>setpagedevice
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. I tried like you said, but i got exception while running the script through gs. Could you please write small example how to write some content from left top corner on different page size?

Comment: This is not working, because i wrote the stamp on the set of existing pdf with different sizes. Because of it's stamping done at existing file with different size, i may not write into the common size. I need to write into the A4 size and then existing file should be render over the existing file, because few files may be scanned images also.

Comment: The example code uses the current media size, whatever that may be, so I don't see what the problem is. In any event, it is up to you to do the work on getting the output you want, not least because you have not at any point clearly described your goal.

Comment: As you told, I have full control over what i want draw. My requirement is to stamp the pdf files upload by users. Because of users uploaded pdf files are scanned letters, mostly those are images wrapped into the PDF. First time, I tired with BeginPage, it's works fine with normal pdf files. If i used some scanned pdf files (each page of pdf file is color or monochrome images only), stamping is not visible. After using EndPage, works fine.Some of scanned files may have different page size,but i require to stamping in the A4 and not in the size of pdf files, which i given at the gs command.

Comment: Hope you understand my requirement, thanks for your favors on this matter. I found few articles to work out this using PDFtk. But, i'm curious to know how to do this by gs and postscript and i don't want to install pdftk into the production server.

Comment: BeginPage draws before the content is drawn, for scanned images the background of the image is white, and so will 'erase' anything written by BeginPage. So EndPage is the way to go. If teh output media is always the same size, then you can have the same drawing commands in the EndPage procedure, I'm not really sure what it is you are asking for.

Comment: If i used EndPage, the currentpage directive returns the scanned pages size, so whatever i wrote it draws on the scanned page size and not in the A4 Size. What i want is, i need to draw the stamping in the A4 Size and it must draw above the scanned pages, so my stamp is visible.

Comment: EndPage should be using the current media size, so the only way that the media size should be the size of the scanned image is if the final output media is that size. This sort of mis-communication is why these discussions should always include an example input file to reproduce the behaviour.